# Small Caps Computer Modern Unicode problem

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, small-caps

I want to use CMU with xelatex for my docs. Everything is working fine except small caps for greek letters. My input (code)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xunicode,fontspec,xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setromanfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is a greek text Ακολουθεί ελληνικό κείμενο\\
\textit{This is a greek text Ακολουθεί ελληνικό κείμενο}\\
\textsc{This is a greek text Ακολουθεί ελληνικό κείμενο}
\end{document}
```

The CMU news mention that ***Added Greek small capitals to CMUSerif-Roman, CMUSerif-Bold, CMUSansSerif, CMUSansSerif-Bold, CMUTypewriter-Regular***

I cannot figure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: There has never been a small caps Greek font, I'm afraid. Are small caps actually used for Greek?

Comment: From http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/news.html
CM Unicode 0.6.2 (March 02 2007) 
...
Added Greek small capitals to CMUSerif-Roman, CMUSerif-Bold, CMUSansSerif, CMUSansSerif-Bold, CMUTypewriter-Regular
....

Comment: I guess that the annotation simply means that something (the normal lowercase glyphs) is printed in a small caps context. There's no glyph named `alpha.sc` in the glyph list for the fonts.

Comment: I've found a [discussion in Typophile.com](http://www.typophile.com/node/83725).

Answer (score 2):

The glyph list in the fonts shows no `alpha.sc` nor other Greek lowercase letters. There are instead the glyphs for *uppercase* Greek letters. Probably the annotation in the Changelog means that the fonts have been adjusted in order to *print* something in a small caps context.

On the other hand, I know of no “small caps Greek” usage. For instance, there's no trace of small caps glyphs in the GFS fonts. I also found a [discussion in Typophile.com](http://www.typophile.com/node/83725), which is quite interesting, but shows that small caps is rarely used for Greek (at least in modern times).

The conclusion is that there is no support for small caps in Greek in the available fonts.